# WorpPress permalink structure cant match category base

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress install where I wanted to change the Permalink settings to give me a url structure like this: "/blog/%category%/%postname%/"

I also want the categories to have the same base "blog"

This would giving me post urls in the form "blog/category/mypost" and category archive pages in the form "blog/category"

The issue is that if both the category base matches the first part of the url, then I get a 404 error when I go to a post.

I am guessing the issue is that if the category base matches the first part of the structure match (blog : blog) then WP looks for a subcategory and not a post.

Is there a way to get around this issue given that I don't need sub-categories in my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your category base from `blog` to `./blog`

Comment: On the money!  That was the one variation I didn't try   

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest way if you just want to customize the permalink of categories and posts, you can do so with the help of [Permalinks Customizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-customizer/).

The other more complex way you can set your WordPress's root url to domain.com/blog instead of domain.com. This involve server (Nginx/Apache) specific configuration (redirect/proxy), and also this will impact others post types ,taxonomies and basically everything else's url. Because your root url is now start with domain.com/blog, so everything will start with /blog/other/path. This method is preferable when your WordPress installation is solely for, let's say blogging purpose. For example, when a company has two WordPress installations, which domain.com is the main application and domain.com/blog is for articles.